# Black Keys implementation in Virtual Piano UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

So, I challenged myself to make a Virtual Piano in UWP. I've managed until now to make the basic UI, where the keys should be placed and using DataBinding I generated all the white keys.

I've got  2 Classes. Sound.cs and SoundManager.cs

In Sounds.cs I've made an overloaded contructor so I can define the name, the color, the image for the black or the white key and the audiofile for the notes.

```
 class Sound
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AudioFile { get; set; }
    public string WhiteImage { get; set; }
    public string BlackImage { get; set; }
    public  KeyColor Color { get; set; }

    public Sound(string name, KeyColor color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Color = color;   

        if(color == KeyColor.Black)
        {
            BlackImage = string.Format("/Assets/Images/{0}.png", color);
            AudioFile = string.Format("/Assets/Audio/{0}.wav", name);
        }
        else if (color == KeyColor.White)
        {
            WhiteImage = string.Format("/Assets/Images/{0}.png", color);
            AudioFile = string.Format("/Assets/Audio/{0}.wav", name);
        }

    }
}

public enum KeyColor
{
    Black,
    White
}
```

In SoundManager.cs I have a method called getSounds in which I add in a List all the notes for the white keys and the black keys as well.

```
class SoundManager
{

    public static void getSounds(ObservableCollection<Sound> sounds)
    {
        var allSounds = WhiteSounds();
        sounds.Clear();
        allSounds.ForEach(p => sounds.Add(p));
    }


    private static List<Sound> getSounds()
    {
        var sounds = new List<Sound>();

        sounds.Add(new Sound("C1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("C#1", KeyColor.Black));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("D1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("D#1", KeyColor.Black));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("E1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("F1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("F#1", KeyColor.Black));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("G1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("G#1", KeyColor.Black));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("A1", KeyColor.White));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("A#1", KeyColor.Black));
        sounds.Add(new Sound("B1", KeyColor.White));

        return sounds;
    }       
}
```

In MainPage.xaml I made GridView which is gonna display all the notes like clickable Images.

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Name="SoundGridView"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          ItemClick="SoundGridView_ItemClick"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Sounds}"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,32,32,0"
                          >

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>


                    <GridView.ItemTemplate >

                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Sound">
                            <RelativePanel>
                                <StackPanel MinHeight="150" MinWidth="50"  Margin="0,0,-12,0" MaxHeight="700" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Image x:Name="WhiteKeys" Stretch="Fill" MinHeight="150" MinWidth="50" Source="{x:Bind WhiteImage}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image x:Name="BlackKeys" Stretch="Fill" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="25" Source="{x:Bind BlackImage}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </RelativePanel>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs I made the ObservableCollection which is needed so I can can Bind the Sounds in the GridView and also I made the click event for the image, so a note is played whenever you press a key.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<Sound> Sounds;    


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Sounds = new ObservableCollection<Sound>();
        SoundManager.GetWhiteSounds(Sounds);  

    }        

    private void SoundGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var sound = (Sound)e.ClickedItem;
        MyMediaElement.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, sound.AudioFile);
    }
}
```

So, my problem so far is that it doesn't run at all when I try to add the Black Keys on the RelativePanel. It throws me an expection like this [Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Z4f.png)

However, when I remove the StackPanel that has the Image for the Black Keys from the Relative Panel

```
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image x:Name="BlackKeys" Stretch="Fill" MinHeight="150" MinWidth="50" Source="{x:Bind BlackImage}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
```

and also I remove the sounds for the black keys in the SoundManager.cs and leave only the sounds for the white keys, the app runs but obviously, there are no black keys in the piano.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that I'm approaching the problem totally wrong. So, is there a way to add both white and black keys like this: [Expectation and Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE8a0.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you're missing the source for the `BlackImage`, check if it is set correctly

Comment: Nope, that's not it. The app is running well if I remove the StackPanel for the White Keys and leave the StackPanel for the Black Keys. So, I guess that the source for the BlackImage is set correctly. Exception is thrown only when I have both StackPanels for White and Black keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you use x:Bind, the `Source` of the `Image` needs to bind to a property of the  `BitmapImage` instead of string, otherwise it will throw a compile-time error.

We should be able to use the `BitmapImage` instead of `string` in the Sound class.

For example:

```
internal class Sound
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AudioFile { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage WhiteImage { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage BlackImage { get; set; }
    public KeyColor Color { get; set; }

    public Sound(string name, KeyColor color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Color = color;

        if (color == KeyColor.Black)
        {
            BlackImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/Black.png"));
            AudioFile = string.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/22.wav", name);
        }
        else if (color == KeyColor.White)
        {
            WhiteImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/White.PNG"));
            AudioFile = string.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Audio/11.wav", name);
        }
    }
}

public enum KeyColor
{
    Black,
    White
}
```

If you want to use the string type to bind the Image, we can use the Binding instead of x:Bind. That we do not need to convert the string to BitmapImage, we should be able to use Image.Source to bind the string.

Comment: @HarisAn Did my answer solved you issue? If not, please tell the detail to us.